# Is it possible to change the voice of the "say" command?

Tags: macos, text-to-speech, say

Is it possible to change the voice that Mac OS X uses for the `say` command? How?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By default it uses the System Voice set in the Text to Speech page of the Speech panel of System Preferences. Otherwise, you can use the `-v` option with one of the named voices:

```
say -v Zarvox "found it in the man page"
say -v Agnes "found it in the man page"
```

Comment: To get a list of the named voices type `say -v ?`.

Comment: `say -v` not working

Comment: With zsh (which is the default OS X shell), you need to escape the question mark: `say -v \?`. Or you can run it within single quotes: `say -v '?'`

Answer (score 4):

man say yields this

```
  -v voice, --voice=voice
       Specify the voice to be used. Default is the voice selected in
       System Preferences.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can permanently change the voice by changing the System Voice in System Preferences -> Dictation & Speech -> Text to Speech

Comment: In macOS Ventura, it’s found in Accessibility → Spoken Content.

Answer (score 2):

You can view/customize different voices on Mac from

System Preferences --> Accessibility --> Speech

[image]